# Spacemacs Magit mode magit-refresh

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

What's the fastest way to get magit to refresh?

Run magit-refresh in spacemacs? The default binding of g is used for vim bindings.

Thus, I've been doing space-g-s, which is the global command.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the latest develop branch and the keybinding is `gr` for `magit-refresh`.

Comment: Should I be using develop? I'm relatively new to spacemacs.

Comment: @justingordon Develop branch is really stable, I'm always been using the develop branch of spacemacs for one year.

Comment: I'm on it and I notice the issue is FIXED!